# Passing data from controller function to controller function before redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **codeigniter** I have an edit page which shows me all information of a vacancy. 
The (Vacancy) controller method to load this view looks like this, it makes sure all data is preloaded.

```
public function editVacancy($vacancyid)
    {
        $this->is_logged_in();
        $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancies_model');

        // Passing Variables
        $data['title'] = 'Titletest';
        $data['class'] = 'vacancy';

        $orgadminuserid = $this->vacancies_model->getOrgAdminUserId($vacancyid);

        if ((!is_null($orgadminuserid)) && ($this->auth_user_id == $orgadminuserid[0]->user_id)) {
            $data['vacancyid'] = $vacancyid;
            $data['vacancy'] = $this->vacancies_model->get($vacancyid);
            $data['test'] = $this->session->flashdata('feedbackdata');

            $partials = array('head' => '_master/header/head', 'navigation' => '_master/header/navigation_dashboard', 'content' => 'dashboard/vacancy/edit_vacancy', 'footer' => '_master/footer/footer');
            $this->template->load('_master/master', $partials, $data);
        }
    }
```

In this view i have different forms for updating different sections.
Every form submit goes to a different method in my **'Vacancy' controller**.

```
    public function saveGeneralInfo()
        {
            $this->is_logged_in();
            $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancies_model');

            $vacancyid = $this->input->post('vacancyid');
            $vacancyUpdateData = $this->vacancies_model->get($vacancyid);

                $result = $this->vacancies_model->update($vacancyid, $vacancyUpdateData);
                if ($result) {
                    $feedbackdata = array(
                       'type'  => 'alert-success',
                       'icon'     => 'fa-check-circle',
                       'title' => 'Success!',
                       'text' => 'De algemene vacature gegevens zijn geupdate.'
                  );
                      $this->session->set_flashdata('feedbackdata', $feedbackdata);
                      redirect("dashboard/vacancy/editVacancy/" . $vacancyid);
                }
            }

    }
```

Where I indicated in my code "//HERE ..." is where I would want the feedback message parameter to pass on to my 'main controller method' which loads the view with the prefilled data. (editVacancy).

Is there a clean way to do this?

EDIT:

I tried using flashdata, i updated the code to have the flashdata inserted.

However when i do a var_dump($test); in my view, it remains null.

EDIT 2: 
I noticed when i put my $_SESSION in a variable in my editVacancy controller method (which is being redirected to) and var_dump it in my view that this does not contain the ci_vars with the flashdata in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `set_header` you can use simple `redirect` function for it.

```
redirect("dashboard/vacancy/editVacancy/".$vacancyid);
```

Comment: Won't this give issues when passing an array variable ?

Comment: according to your question `$vacancyid` single value. if array you can split and pass it. Or can use flashdata also

Comment: I want the $feedbackmsg parameters passed on, which is an array. is it a good idea to be sending all the error strings back in the URL with redirect ?

Comment: so best way for your case is use FlashData. Know it ??

Comment: I will google it out, have not heard of it before Thankyou for pointing me in another direction!

Comment: Ok Hold on will give you some links

Comment: You can check this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Comment: @Dennis: this is better

Comment: @Dennis Try it. Learn it. If anything goes wrong can ask too

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i tried implementing it but I did not manage to get it working. I updated my code to have the flashdata bit inserted, could u take a look at what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: once you set the flsah data you have to use `redirect` function

Comment: I am using $this->session->set_flashdata('feedbackdata', $feedbackdata);
                      redirect("dashboard/vacancy/editVacancy/" . $vacancyid);

Comment: make sure this `if ((!is_null($orgadminuserid)) && ($this->auth_user_id == $orgadminuserid[0]->user_id)) {` can reachable

Comment: I managed to get it working, I had to use keep_flashdata because it seems there is a random other request passing through! Thank you so much for the tips :)